# How to set Camera preview Orientation using google vision api

Tags: android, android-camera, google-vision

I see a lot of example on how to do this involving the the original Camera API but not using googles api in the google play services SDK. I'm trying to use it for QR scanning but cannot get the preview to be in portrait mode since they use a object called CameraSource there is no set orientation function available. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need recently while using ZXing library. I couldn't get the camera in portrait mode while scanning, causing the data in the result to be lost when the screen rotated back to portrait after the landscape preview.

To semi rectify the issue I just used the following tag within the AndroidManifest.xml file;

`<android:screenOrientation="portrait">`

Although this did not solve the orientation of the camera preview it stopped me losing the returned results.